# A diophantine equation

Tags: diophantine-equations

I'm trying to determine the ideal class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{223})$ using elementary methods.

Is there an easy way to show that $a^2 - 223b^2 = - 3$ has no integer solutions?
I've tried reducing mod just about everything I could think of, but that doesn't seem to help.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go [here](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM) and put in the equation and click on "step-by-step" and you will get a proof that there are no solutions. Basically, the left side is so small that any solution has to come from the continued fraction for $\sqrt{223}$, but this has a very short period, and $-3$ doesn't show up.